# Place widgets relative to right side tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to place widgets using the `.place()` method. I understand that `x` and `y` are measured from the top left side of the page, but I'm trying to change it, so it can measure it from the top right.

My reason being, I would like the label to always be a constant distance from the right side of the page. I've tried `relx` and `rely` but unfortunately it didn't work for me, and for some reason neither is the anchor.

Can anyone help with this?

Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')
root.configure(bg='blue')
label = Label(root,text='Hello',anchor='nw')
label.place(x=50,y=50)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Read up on [When to use the Place Manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm), [When to use the Pack Manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm) and [When to use the Grid Manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try giving x and y co-ordinates to widgets, something like this,

```
import tkinter as tk
root=tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x300')
b1=tk.Button(root,text="b1",width=12)
b1.place(relx = 1, x =-2, y = 2, anchor = 'ne')
b2=tk.Button(root,text="b2",width=12)
b2.place(relx = 1, x =-2, y = 30, anchor = 'ne')
root.mainloop()
```

hope this helps you!